# accessing github organisation repos in cloudformation

Tags: github, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

is there a way to access github organisation repos when creating a cloudformation template for Pipelines? I can access my personal repos using a standard personal access token, but when putting in my organisation name in credentials it cannot access the repo. I am an admin of the organisation so I have full access.

This is how I am currently using the credentials:

```
Pipeline:
Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
Properties:
  RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineRole.Arn
  Stages:
  - Name: Source
    Actions:
    - InputArtifacts: []
      Name: Source
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Source
        Owner: ThirdParty
        Version: '1'
        Provider: GitHub
      OutputArtifacts:
      - Name: SourceOutput
      Configuration:
        Owner: !Ref GitHubUser
        Repo: !Ref GitHubRepo
        Branch: !Ref GitHubBranch
        OAuthToken: !Ref GitHubToken
```

Thanks in advance